A Variable Font with an Italic axis on MSWord on Mac
I have been strugling to get my font (converted from glyphs using fonttools but that's not so important) to work well in MS Word on Mac. To keep it simple, I have only kept wght between Light(300) and Regular(400), and ital between 0 and 11, with preset styles Light, Regular, Light Italic, (Regular) Italic.
Now, when I install the font on Mac, all looks well in font book, and all looks well in the mac built-in text editor. The trouble is when I select the font in MS Word.
When the font is generated by fonttools, it does not have the STAT table, and in MS-Word I only have Italic listed twice:

I found out that some fonts have a STAT table, so I tried to add one. The result is better but still not OK:

I have been playing with the STAT table and with the fvar table to no avail. I also tried to find a font that works, but I didn't find any with an Italic axis. My STAT table:
    <STAT>
      <Version value="0x00010001"/>
      <DesignAxisRecordSize value="8"/>
      <!-- DesignAxisCount=2 -->
      <DesignAxisRecord>
        <Axis index="0">
          <AxisTag value="wght"/>
          <AxisNameID value="256"/>  <!-- Weight -->
          <AxisOrdering value="0"/>
        </Axis>
        <Axis index="1">
          <AxisTag value="ital"/>
          <AxisNameID value="257"/>  <!-- Italic -->
          <AxisOrdering value="1"/>
        </Axis>
      </DesignAxisRecord>
      <!-- AxisValueCount=4 -->
      <AxisValueArray>
        <AxisValue index="0" Format="1">
          <AxisIndex value="0"/>
          <Flags value="0"/>
          <ValueNameID value="258"/>  <!-- Light -->
          <Value value="300.0"/>
        </AxisValue>
        <AxisValue index="1" Format="3">
          <AxisIndex value="0"/>
          <Flags value="2"/>  <!-- ElidableAxisValueName -->
          <ValueNameID value="260"/>  <!-- Regular -->
          <Value value="400.0"/>
          <LinkedValue value="750.0"/>
        </AxisValue>
        <AxisValue index="2" Format="3">
          <AxisIndex value="1"/>
          <Flags value="2"/>  <!-- ElidableAxisValueName -->
          <ValueNameID value="282"/>  <!-- Roman -->
          <Value value="0.0"/>
          <LinkedValue value="11.0"/>
        </AxisValue>
        <AxisValue index="3" Format="1">
          <AxisIndex value="1"/>
          <Flags value="0"/>
          <ValueNameID value="257"/>  <!-- Italic -->
          <Value value="11.0"/>
        </AxisValue>
      </AxisValueArray>
      <ElidedFallbackNameID value="2"/>  <!-- Regular -->
    </STAT>

So, my question: Has anybody been able to generate a ttf with an Italic axis and some preset styles that works fine in MS Word on Mac? Thanks.

How is this programming-related?

Will need to find out how to call the right sequence of commands using fonttools and possibly others to generate such fvar and STAT (or other) tables for MS Word to be satisfied. That's how.

None of what you said has anything to do with programming.
